# delimited URIs in comments cause broken links

Tags: bug, comments

Steps to reproduce:

Add a comment:

> `foo bar <http://example.com>.`

Expected result, a comment showing as:

> foo bar http://example.com.

The URI reference is `http://example.com`. It's url styling ends with the last `m`.

Instead, the text shown is:

> foo bar <[http://example.com>](http://example.com%3E);.

With a less-than sign before and a semicolon after (which both shouldn't be shown).

The URI reference is `http://example.com>`, note the extra greater-than sign at the end. It's url styling ends with the `>`.

**Rationale**:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-C

Comment: foo bar <http://example.com>. - source: `foo bar <http://example.com>.`

Comment: foo bar http://example.com. - source: `foo bar http://example.com.`

Comment: The formatter used for the comments (called MarkdownMini) is different from the one used in posts. This seems to be a MarkdownMini bug.

Comment: It also happens using quotes: "http://es.stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro this exactly (in the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)):

```
foo bar <http://example.com>.
```

Was displayed as:

```
foo bar <example.com>;.
```

This is different from what you report as your output.

```
foo bar <h̲t̲t̲p̲:̲/̲/̲e̲x̲a̲m̲p̲l̲e̲.̲c̲o̲m̲>̲;.
```

Note [Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) says:

> Bare URLs
>
> We have modified our Markdown parser to support "naked" URLs (in most
>   but not all cases -- beware of unusual characters in your URLs); they
>   will be converted to links automatically:
>
> I often visit `http://example.com.`
>
> Force URLs by enclosing them in angle brackets:
>
> Have you seen `<http://example.com>?`
>
> URLs can be relative or full.

So both your test output and my test output (although different) do not appear to match the help text.

- They both have a `;` that shouldn't be there
- My test output is missing `http://`

Comment: I reproduced it in comments on the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, you reproduced my test output (which is different to the OP's reported output).

Comment: Oh, I see, missing http in the rendered output.